# what's the compare content for < > when compare random access iterator such as vector in c++?

Tags: c++, iterator

What's the compare content for `<` or `>`  when comparing random access iterators such as those of a `std::vector` in C++?

Does it compare pointer address or pointed content?

Why do other iterator types not support `<` and `>` but `!=`?

Comment: What's "compare content"?

Comment: I mean how to understand < > when comparing iterator?

Comment: pretty much like comparing two pointers. The others are not continuous so < or > is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

In general, all random-access iterators support relational comparisons, because for them such comparisons can be evaluated easily, immediately and efficiently.

Relational comparisons for random-access iterators do not compare "pointer address or pointed content". (What pointers are you talking about, BTW?) When you compare random-access iterators with `<` or `>`, it simply tells you witch iterator refers to a earlier element of the container. The closer the container element is to the beginning of the container, the "smaller" the corresponding iterator will appear to relational comparison operators. Think of it as of comparing *indices* of the container elements the iterators are referring to. How such comparison is implemented internally is an implementation detail. In case of `std::vector` it will typicaly boil down to pointer comparison. In case og `std::deque` it will be more complicated, but still quite efficient.

The same logic can be applied to non-random-access iterators, meaning that non-random-access iterators can also be seen as ordered in accordance withh the same principle. But for non-random-access iterators there's typically no efficient immediate way to say, which one is "larger" and which one is "smaller". It is not possible to say right away which iterator points to an earlier element in the non-random-accessible container. This is the reason such iterators do not support relational comparison operators.